# Boostrap - What Should the Search Form Width Be?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**We need to achieve that the search form with search button fill the entire column area.**

UPDATE:

I have a simplified version of code which can be viewed here:  http://jsfiddle.net/persianturtle/Trgr6/10/

Another, previous jsFiddle version is here:

Here is the live example http://jsfiddle.net/Trgr6/3/

You will see black area as an example of the entire area to fill in the old version.

In the new version, I tried to set the width of the search form to the width of the:

```
.row-fluid .span9 { }
```

Class width, which is:

```
width: 74.46808510638297%;
```

And the code:

```
<div class="searchbar">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row-fluid">     
            <div id ="test" class="span9">

                 <form class="form-search">
                     <div class="input-append span12">
                        <input type="text" class= "search-query" placeholder="Enter Search">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>
                    </div>
                 </form>

            </div>      

            <div class="span3 info">
                .span3 column
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @madth3, What? How?  I was trying to add the CSS tag to the question, otherwise nobody will see it!

Comment: Alex and I have been working on this together for about an hour now. I'm extremely curious to see the best way to solve this issue.

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah As it reads now, there is a lot of code but the original purpose was removed. I have no idea what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @madth3, and what do you mean, the question is not missing at all.  It is visible only on the bootstrap tag.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you mean.  The question is:  Boostrap - What Should the Search Form Width Be?

Comment: What should it be for what?

Comment: The question is how to make the search field with search button fill the entire column area. that simple.

Comment: Simple, yes but it was taken from the question. When editing please think about how the question will read for a complete newcomer to the problem.

Comment: @madth3 do you think we can find a solution?

Comment: I think he is under the impression that I *removed* the question, which I did not, I only added.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if I updated your Fiddle or not, but yeh. This will work.

http://jsfiddle.net/xWTuF/2/

Override the input append from inline-block to block and give it a padding-right equal to that of the overall button width and the padding on the input.
Give the input a width of 100%;

```
.container .form-search .input-append {
    display:block;
    padding-right:99px
}
.input-append input.search-query {
    width:100%
}
```

Oh I also removed the span12, you dont need it. Reorganised the html to:

```
<div class="searchbar">
    <div class="container"> 
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span9">
                <form class="form-search">
                    <div class="input-append">
                        <input type="text" class="search-query">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>
                     </div>
                </form> 
            </div>
            <div class="span3 info">
                .span3 column
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you see that you moved the spa3 column below the span9?